# Web-based MongoDB (Mongo-express) how to use middleware

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new at nodejs and I gues therefor I can't get to it. 
I'm trying to install https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express as middleware (I got it to work as standalone app).
I did those three steps

> var mongo_express = require('mongo-express/lib/middleware')
>
> var mongo_express_config = require('./mongo_express_config')
>
> app.use('/mongo_express', mongo_express(mongo_express_config))

And after that not sure how to reach it(how do I run it). I hoped for the port 8081 to be active but it's not. 
Can anyone help me and explain how this supposed to work?

Comment: did you start your `mongo` instance?

Comment: Yes I start it, I'm getting log message that it's connected to the database (message from mongo-express middleware I think) when I ran my application.

Comment: `Mongo-express` is just a UI for `MongoDB`.   When you run the `Mongo-Express` instance you should see the `collections` in database and you can edit them through a simple User Interface.  Also `Mongo-Express` is meant for development purpose. It cannot be used for Production.   Try using `Mongoose` as ORM for MongoDB.

Comment: I know that it's UI for MongoDB, that's what I'm after. For now I'm runing it localy on my PC while developing, it works fine for one project. What I would like to get is to run for the project while in development mode. f.e. if I have a my project1 runing under project1.com so I would type project1.com:8081 then UI comes up, allready connected to the rigth DB with rigth user name and password (those I have to change between projects). Ofcourse I'm not sure if that's even possible.